# trouble repeating (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I was trying to throw together a simple Rock, paper, scissors simulator to impress my sister, so I did, but the randomization part of the code wasn't working every time. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <button type="button" onclick="rps(1)">Rock</button>

  <button type="button" onclick="rps(2)">Paper</button>

  <button type="button" onclick="rps(3)">Scissors</button>

    <script>
var ai= null;
var rps=function(type){
ai= Math.floor(Math.random()+1*3);
  switch(ai){
  case 1:
    switch(type){
      case 1:
        alert("Tie");
      break;
      case 2:
        alert("Win");
      break;
      case 3:
        alert("Loose");
      break;
    }
  break;
  case 2:
      switch(type){
      case 1:
        alert("Loose");
      break;
      case 2:
        alert("Tie");
      break;
      case 3:
        alert("Win");
      break;
    }
  break;
  case 3:
    switch(type){
      case 1:
        alert("Loose");
      break;
      case 2:
        alert("Tie");
      break;
      case 3:
        alert("Win");
      break;
    }
  break;
  default:
    alert("Error");
  break;}
      };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what I did wrong, how I can improve on this in the future, and what can be done to salvage this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your semantics of `Math.random` are wrong. Try this:

```
ai = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
```

Now you get Win, Lose, or Tie randomly

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
ai= Math.floor(Math.random()+1*3);
```

You have to remember that math operators have a certain order. Multiplication happens before addition, so the way it is written it means take `1 * 3` (or 3), and add it or `Math.random()`. I would guess you are always getting 3. The best and clearest solution is usually to use parentheses. Here is how it should be written:

```
ai = (Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <button type="button" onclick="rps(1)">Rock</button>

  <button type="button" onclick="rps(2)">Paper</button>

  <button type="button" onclick="rps(3)">Scissors</button>

    <script>
var ai= null;
var rps=function(type){

  var typeArray= ['','Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
ai= Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
 alert(typeArray[type]);

 if(type ===1)
 {
   if(ai ===1)
   {
    alert("draws with rock"); 
   }

   else if(ai ===2)
   {
     alert("loss to paper");
   }

   else if(ai ===3)
   {
     alert("win vs scissors");
   }
 }

 else if(type ===2)
 {
   if(ai ===1)
   {
    alert("win vs rock"); 
   }

   else if(ai ===2)
   {
     alert("draw paper");
   }

   else if(ai ===3)
   {
     alert("loss vs scissors");
   } 
 }

 else
 {
    if(ai ===1)
   {
    alert("loss vs rock"); 
   }

   else if(ai ===2)
   {
     alert("win vs paper");
   }

   else if(ai ===3)
   {
     alert("draw with scissors");
   }
 }
      };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works. It can be done a lot better, with no If's and more efficient code. But that's in line with the level of what you did.